# Strange issue with a variable return by a post request

Tags: php, variables, post

Ok I have the code:

```
function forgotPassword(){
var email = $("#forgotEmail").val();
var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
if(email == null){
    $("#screenContainer2").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "You must fill in your email";
    $("#warningCasing").animate({height: "178px"}, 700);
    return false;
}
if(email == ""){
    $("#screenContainer2").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "You must fill in your email";
    $("#warningCasing").animate({height: "178px"}, 700);
    return false;
}
if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
    $("#screenContainer2").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "Not a valid e-mail address";
    $("#warningCasing").animate({height: "178px"}, 700);
    return false;
}
$.post("forgotPassword.php", {"email":email}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data == "success"){
        $("#screenContainer2").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "Your request has been recieved, you should recieve an email shortly confirming your password.";
        $("#warningCasing").animate({height: "178px"}, 700);
        $("#forgotPasswordDiv").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#screenContainer").fadeOut("slow");
    }
    if(data == "found"){
        $("#screenContainer2").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "There has been an error, please try again.";
        $("#warningCasing").animate({height: "178px"}, 700);
        return false;
    }
    if(data == "failed"){
        console.log("hello");
        $("#screenContainer2").fadeIn();
        document.getElementById("warningMessage").innerHTML = "We could not find an account with that email.";
        $("#warningCasing").animate({height: "178px"}, 700);
        return false;
    }
});
}
```

I've got 2 console.log points in it. The first tells me what data is the second should run if data == "failed". The problem is that even when data == "failed" as logged by the first console.log the second isn't logging.

I changed the last if statement to else to see what would happen, and the code it contains fires. For some reason the data being returned by the post request is being recognised by the following if statements. I really am stuck on this one. I know the php file is ok, returns 200 in network tab and the first console.log testifies that all is working correctly. Just for some reason the if statements aren't being recognised.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using trim on the data like below or check your php file if it has any extra line or space after closing tag. Sometimes in the php code if there is extra line or a extra space after the ending php tag this can happen as the returned value may be "failed\n" and not "failed".

```
data = $.trim(data)
```

Comment: great, I have actually come across that sort of thing before, thanks for reminding me. I'll try it.

Comment: it worked thanks. I didn't use the trim function, but deleted the extra white space. Thanks.